# Cannot resolve symbol parse

Tags: parsing, dependencies

experts out there! I need your help. I am trying to make my own instant messenger. I refer to this [website](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing), and I am stuck at this. There is a read underline bottom of the word, 'parse' and it says Cannot resolve symbol parse. I did everything I could. I put parse-1.10.2.zip in libs file. I added compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs'), compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.2.jar') in build gradle, and added the jar in dependencies. However, the error still there. Can anybody fix this problem? Here's my code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION ID", "CLIENT KEY");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you extracted your zip-archive? I'm no expert but you should put the jar-Files into libs-directory - not a zip-file.

Otherwise try [this templates](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new):